"Doing the Countess's little woolly lamb to perfection" in "The Seven Dials Mystery"
I'm reading Agatha Christie's The Seven Dials Mystery. I came across this passage where Jimmy is talking to Miss Wade about Bill, and he says this:

He's doing the Countess's little woolly lamb to perfection.

What does that mean? Does it mean he's trying to woo her?

Interesting! The context (two sentences later, about the Countess being beautiful and Bill having "a heart like an hotel") would suggest that your interpretation is correct, but I've never heard such a phrase and can't find any trace of it anywhere else.

Jimmy Thesiger had introduced the idea that Bill might be in love with the Countess, but Loraine Wade disagreed:

“Bill ought to look after her [Bundle],” suggested Loraine.
“Bill’s pretty busy elsewhere.” [said Jimmy]
“Don’t you believe it,” said Loraine.
“What? Not the Countess? But the lad’s potty about her.”
Agatha Christie (1929). The Seven Dials Mystery, chapter 25. London: Collins.

Loraine says that “it’s not the Countess with Bill—it’s Bundle.” But this raises the question of the relationship between Bill and the Countess, which Loraine explains as follows:

“Don’t you think it possible that Bill is doing a bit of sleuthing on his own?”
“Bill? He hasn’t got the brains.”
“I’m not so sure. When a simple, muscular person like Bill does set out to be subtle, no one ever gives him credit for it.”

In this context, we can explain Jimmy’s remark that Bill is “doing the Countess’s little woolly lamb to perfection” as follows. “Do” means “play the part”:

do, v. 19.a. transitive. To enact, act, perform; to play the part of; to impersonate, mimic
Oxford English Dictionary.

and a “lamb” is someone who is innocent:

lamb, n. 2.b. One who is as meek, gentle, innocent, or weak as a lamb.
Oxford English Dictionary.

So Jimmy means that Bill is successfully pretending that he is innocent of spying on the Countess. There is also a suggestion that Bill has been following the Countess around, as in the nursery rhyme:

Mary had a little lamb,
Its fleece was white as snow,
And everywhere that Mary went,
The lamb was sure to go.

